# NSFileManager: not working properly

Tags: ios, nsfilemanager

I am using below code to save and read saved clicked image file from document directory. Its working well for the first time but when i'm trying to read the saved image file for the second time, its showing me the image clicked during first time.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
    didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image
              editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
{

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                         NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:
                      @"test.png" ];

    NSFileManager* fileManager=[NSFileManager defaultManager];
    if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:path]) {
        NSError* error;
        [fileManager removeItemAtPath:path error:&error];
    }
    NSData* data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
    [data writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
    [self.viewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Any idea why every time its returning me image clicked for the first time.

Comment: are you sure that, whenever file exists you need to remove that file?

Comment: The method you show doesn't return anything. How are you loading the image for display?

Comment: And check the return value of `writeToFile:atomically:` !

Comment: @MartinR:My writeToFile:atomically: is returning True

Comment: @Wain:I'm reading the image file from the same path of test.png....i.e on every click i'm overwriting image file and its getting changed in Document directory but while reading its returning me first clicked image.

Answer (score 1):

`didFinishPickingImage:` is deprecated since iOS3.

This should work:

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];

    if (!image) {

        image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    }

    if (image) {

        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                         NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString* path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.png" ];

        NSData* data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
        [data writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
        [self.viewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Please check the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate_Protocol/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007069-CH3-DontLinkElementID_1).